# Which layer is the right one for custom overlays?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am creating a custom overlay extending google.maps.OverlayView and I got a bit puzzled when it came to attaching my dom elements to the layers of which an overlay is composed of. Here's some pseudo code:

```
   MyOverlay = function(latlng) {
      this.latlng = latlng;    
      this.root = document.createElement('div');
      this.root.style.postion = "absolute";
      this.root.style.height = "20px";
      this.root.style.width = "20px";
      this.root.style.background = "red";
   };

   MyOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

   MyOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
      var panes = this.getPanes();
      panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div); // <<< is it the right layer?
   };

   MyOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
      var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
      var point = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng);
      var panes = this.getPanes();
      panes.overlayLayer.style.left = position.x - 10 + 'px'; // -10 to center it horizontally
      panes.overlayLayer.style.top = position.y - 10 + 'px'; // -10 to center it vertically
   };
```

As you can see I am using the `overlayLayer` layr to attach my overlay to the map but my question is: "is it the right layer?"

I appreciate it works fine but why one layer and not another? Why not `overlayImage` for instance?

Ta

Comment: It will depend on what this layer will be used for.

Comment: Can you provide some examples?

Comment: For example it's important to know if the user should be able to interact with the Overlay(should it receive Mouse-Events), or if it should be covered by other Overlays (Markers, infoWindows etc. ) or not.